# check if one string is interleaved by two other strings

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am debugging the following problem. Post detailed problem statement and the coding. My question is whether the last else if (`else if (A[i-1]==C[i+j-1] && B[j-1]==C[i+j-1])`) is necessary? I think it is not necessary since it is always covered either by `else if(A[i-1]==C[i+j-1] && B[j-1]!=C[i+j-1])`, or covered by `else if (A[i-1]!=C[i+j-1] && B[j-1]==C[i+j-1])`, i.e. previous two if-else check conditions. Thanks.

Given s1, s2, s3, find whether s3 is formed by the interleaving of s1 and s2.

For example,
Given:
s1 = "aabcc",
s2 = "dbbca",

When s3 = "aadbbcbcac", return true.
When s3 = "aadbbbaccc", return false.

```
// The main function that returns true if C is
// an interleaving of A and B, otherwise false.
bool isInterleaved(char* A, char* B, char* C)
{
    // Find lengths of the two strings
    int M = strlen(A), N = strlen(B);

    // Let us create a 2D table to store solutions of
    // subproblems.  C[i][j] will be true if C[0..i+j-1]
    // is an interleaving of A[0..i-1] and B[0..j-1].
    bool IL[M+1][N+1];

    memset(IL, 0, sizeof(IL)); // Initialize all values as false.

    // C can be an interleaving of A and B only of sum
    // of lengths of A & B is equal to length of C.
    if ((M+N) != strlen(C))
       return false;

    // Process all characters of A and B
    for (int i=0; i<=M; ++i)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<=N; ++j)
        {
            // two empty strings have an empty string
            // as interleaving
            if (i==0 && j==0)
                IL[i][j] = true;

            // A is empty
            else if (i==0 && B[j-1]==C[j-1])
                IL[i][j] = IL[i][j-1];

            // B is empty
            else if (j==0 && A[i-1]==C[i-1])
                IL[i][j] = IL[i-1][j];

            // Current character of C matches with current character of A,
            // but doesn't match with current character of B
            else if(A[i-1]==C[i+j-1] && B[j-1]!=C[i+j-1])
                IL[i][j] = IL[i-1][j];

            // Current character of C matches with current character of B,
            // but doesn't match with current character of A
            else if (A[i-1]!=C[i+j-1] && B[j-1]==C[i+j-1])
                IL[i][j] = IL[i][j-1];

            // Current character of C matches with that of both A and B
            else if (A[i-1]==C[i+j-1] && B[j-1]==C[i+j-1])
                IL[i][j]=(IL[i-1][j] || IL[i][j-1]) ;
        }
    }

    return IL[M][N];
}
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: I think you do need the last case. For example, what happens when `A="aaaa"`, `B="aaaa"`, and `C="aaaaaaaa"`.

Comment: Also, there are other problems in your algorithm. For example, I do not see anywhere where you set any element of `IL[][]` to `false`. Your function probably always returns `true`. You probably need a final `else` block where `IL[i][j]` should be set to `false`.

Comment: @crayzeewulf, thanks for the response, I do not quite catch your ideas. Why in your sample, previous two else-if never already covers and handles well? Thanks.

Comment: @crayzeewulf, thanks for the catch, "You probably need a final else block where IL[i][j] should be set to false". I think I can initialize IL to false at the beginning, the same effect, correct?

Comment: Put a breakpoint or a print in that last `else if` block and see if the program gets there in the example case I mentioned above. As the comments in the code say, the previous two `else if` statements will not catch the condition where a character in C matches characters in both A and B.

Comment: @crayzeewulf, got what you mean, pretty cool. Do you think I an rewrite the code to be more elegant, saying if (A[i-1]==C[i+j-1] || B[j-1]==C[i+j-1]), then IL[i][j]=(IL[i-1][j] || IL[i][j-1])? I mean using the statement to replace all last 3 else-if. Correct? Thanks.

Comment: I think it is cleaner the way it is. However, I do suggest replacing the use of `char*` with `std::string`. If you want to keep using `char*`, at least declare the parameters `const char*` since you are not modifying them. This way you can call the function with string literals and `const` strings. For example, `isInterleaved("aaa", b, c)`.

Comment: @crayzeewulf, accepted, thanks for all the help. Thanks. Good weekend. :)

Comment: Done. But don't hesitate to [answer your own questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). It is okay and encouraged. :D

Comment: Done my rating as well. Good weekend. :)

Comment: No. The condition in the last elseif is mutually excusiuve with the previous two conditions. Also your code relies on VLAs that standard C++ doesn't have, and never set any element to `false`. Perhaps your particular compiler guarantees to initialize `bool` VLAs to false, I can't tell.

Comment: @n.m., what do you mean VLAs?

Comment: Variable length arrays.

Comment: @n.m., which line of my code is VLA? I am confused. Appreciate for pointing out in more details. :)

Comment: `bool IL[M+1][N+1];` This is not standard. Dimensions must be constant expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need the final `else if` to catch the cases when the next character in C matches the next character in both A and B. For example, run your program with `A="aaaa"`, `B="aaaa"`, and `C="aaaaaaaa"` and see if you enter that last `else if` block.

Additionally, you also need a final `else` block to handle cases when none of the previous conditions match. In this case, you need to set `IL[i][j]` to `false`. Otherwise, the function will incorrectly return `true`.

Edit: Even though the code uses `memset` to initialize all elements of `IL` to `0`, it may not work because [ISO C++ does not support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1887178/1062948) variable length arrays (VLAs). In fact, this is what happened when I [tried the code at cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/4mskk). It uses g++-4.9.2 with flags that causes it to report `sizeof(IL)` to be `1` even though `g++` is supposed to support VLAs. Maybe this is a compiler bug or maybe it does not support multidimensional VLAs. In any case, it might be safer to not use them at all.